# Does Windows Phone 8 support an InputScope equivalent to Text or Chat only without Emoji?

Tags: windows-phone-8

For my WP8 app, the server does not support emoji, but I want all the other features of the text/chat inputscope (including autocomplete/autosuggest), just with emoji removed. I would use chat or text, but having the emoji button on the on-screen keyboard implicitly suggests that it is supported, when it isn't.

Is there such a thing as a text InputScope without emoji?

Answer (score 0):

for `InputScope` of `TextBox` in windows phone 8, you need to use `WindowsPhone-Toolkit` library. Kindly check `PhoneTextBox` from [this library](https://phone.codeplex.com/).

**Code:**

first of all, in xaml code of page, add this:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

and then use below code to add `PhoneTextBox`:

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox x:Name="tbxEmail" Hint="Enter your email address"
                                          Margin="0 20 0 10" Height="80"
                                          InputScope="EmailNameOrAddress" 
                                          Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#FF0099CC"
                                          KeyDown="tbxEmail_KeyDown"/>
```

Here you can access `InputScope`.

Hope that helps..!

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBox Name="txtPhoneNumber" >
    <TextBox.InputScope>
        <InputScope>
            <InputScopeName = "Search" />
        </InputScope>
    </TextBox.InputScope>
</TextBox>
```

See this:

http://edu-kinect.com/blog/2014/06/10/understanding-the-input-scope-property-in-window-phone-8/